# Getting values not equals x in boost's multi_index_container

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

I'm trying to get a iterator to all values that are not equal a certain value in `boost::multi_index_container`.

The index I want to access is a `hashed_non_unique` integer. Using `equal_range(0)` on my container which serves as a mapping database, I'm able to access all container entries that have this specific index set to zero.

What I need is a function that returns me all entries where the index is not zero. I searched the web for hours and only [found](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/hash_indices.html) the overloaded function

```
std::pair<iterator,iterator> equal_range(
    const CompatibleKey& x,
    const CompatibleHash& hash,const CompatiblePred& eq)const;
```

But the boost documentation only has few examples and there is none for this specific problem. I do not know what a CompatibleHash or a CompatiblePred is, but I tried with:

```
    m_mappingDb->get<tags::myIndex>().equal_range(m_mappingDb->begin(), 0, 
        [=](uint32_t lhs, uint32_t rhs) { return lhs != rhs; });
```

after finding examples of people using an lambda as sort function in the `multi_index_container`.

When compiling, I then receive a C2664 in that lambda expression that a conversion from `boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_index_iterator<Node,BucketArray,Category>` to `uint32_t` is not possible. So, I'm expecting that my lambda must use iterators as parameters, but which exactly? What is Node, BucketArray and Category?

There is another C2064 in that lambda expression that states that this is not a function that takes 1 argument. Of course, it takes 2. Do I have to compare against this instead?

My alternative is to use `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` instead and set the lower bound to 1 and the upper bound to the maximum value of uint32_t. But, in my opinion, this is ugly as hell. There must be a correct way to implement something like a not equals function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `equal_range(k)` returns a *range* (a pair of iterators in this context) as it relies on the fact that elements whose key is `k` are stored adjacently along the container sequence:

[image]

On the other hand, the elements whose key is *not* equal to `k` are not adjacent, but belong in two disjoint ranges:

[image]

So there is no way `equal_range` can be twisted to return this pair of ranges. If you absolutely need to treat the two ranges as one logical range you can resort to [Boost.Range's `join`](https://www.boost.org/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/join.html):

```
template<typename Container,typename Key>
auto not_equal_range(const Container& c,const Key& k)
{
  auto rng=c.equal_range(k);
  return boost::range::join(
    boost::make_iterator_range(c.begin(),rng.first),
    boost::make_iterator_range(rng.second,c.end()));
}
```

Complete example follows.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1972dbca135e3a69)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range_core.hpp>
#include <boost/range/join.hpp>

template<typename Container,typename Key>
auto not_equal_range(const Container& c,const Key& k)
{
  auto rng=c.equal_range(k);
  return boost::range::join(
    boost::make_iterator_range(c.begin(),rng.first),
    boost::make_iterator_range(rng.second,c.end()));
}

using namespace boost::multi_index;
using container=multi_index_container<
  int,
  indexed_by<
    hashed_non_unique<identity<int>>
  >
>;

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  container c={0,0,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,7};
  for(auto x:not_equal_range(c,4))std::cout<<x<<" ";
}
```

**Output**

```
0 0 1 1 2 2 3 5 6 6 6 7
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this very detailed and insightful explanation of the mechanics behind the equal_range!

Comment: If I understand the circumstance that the equal_range relies on keys laying adjacently in the container correctly, this means that equal_range won't return all entries of one key when they were not added sequentially? After storing [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2], equal_range(2) would only return two instead of three entries?

Comment: @Niklas, no, all keys would be returned as insertion order is not guaranteed, precisely to keep same-key elements together